# How to install Radius MFA on FIPS enabled Amazon Linux server

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel, radius, fips

I am trying to install Radius MFA on my FIPS compliant Linux server but I am getting errors related to MD5

"md5_dgst.c(82): OpenSSL internal error, assertion failed: Digest MD5 forbidden in FIPS mode!"

I understand that MD5 is not FIPS compliant. Can someone assist me with the steps to install Radius MFA with certain cipher like SHA1, SHA2, etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing the freeradius package you will likely need to set an environment variable to load non-FIPS compliant MD5 ciphers for RADIUS. There is a bit of discussion around this on RHEL forums. Different versions may support different env vars.

I successfully got freeradius v3.0.26 installed and working on Amazon Linux2 by setting `OPENSSL_FIPS_NON_APPROVED_MD5_ALLOW=1`. You can test this by running radius in debug mode:

```
OPENSSL_FIPS_NON_APPROVED_MD5_ALLOW=1 radiusd -X
```

From a client use `radclient` or `radtest` to make an auth request.

Once you've proven it works you can modify the systemd unit with this environment var:

```
...
[Service]
Environment=OPENSSL_FIPS_NON_APPROVED_MD5_ALLOW=1
...
```

Next make sure to reload systemd `systemcl daemon-reload` and then you can start the service.

See these links for more details:

- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1872689
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1958979
- [https://networkradius.com/articles/2020/10/28/freeradius-fips.html#:~:text=As%20FreeRADIUS%20uses%20cryptographic%20protocols,is%20the%20most%20truthful%20one](https://networkradius.com/articles/2020/10/28/freeradius-fips.html#:%7E:text=As%20FreeRADIUS%20uses%20cryptographic%20protocols,is%20the%20most%20truthful%20one).